# Pure Javascript library for getting MP4 video metadata online

Tags: library, javascript

I'm writing a [user](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Main_Page) [script](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Greasemonkey) for downloading videos. The flash player of the web site use a JSON file.
The purpose of my script is to get the url of the video by downloading and parsing the video according to the web page. Currently it can download an extract the URL of the videos successfully.

The important part of the JSON file look like this :

```
    {
        "ammProfile": "AMM-HBBTV",
        "version": "VF",
        "versionProg": "1",
        "VFO": "HBBTV",
        "VMT": "mp4",
        "VUR": "http://vo.llnwd.net/v2/am/HBBTV/051332-074-A_SQ_2_VF_01464306_MP4-2200_AMM-HBBTV.mp4"
    }, {
        "ammProfile": "AMM-HBBTV",
        "version": "VF",
        "versionProg": "1",
        "VFO": "HBBTV",
        "VMT": "mp4",
        "VUR": "http://vo.llnwd.net/v2/am/HBBTV/051332-074-A_EQ_2_VF_01464315_MP4-1500_AMM-HBBTV.mp4"
    }
```

Both URL here are about the same video, this just is just the resolution which change.

So, **Which library I can use to parse the relevant metadata without downloading the file completely?** *(maybe with ajax?)*

Comment: *note* : this look possible *(at least)* for audio files with mp4js.